# Schur decomposition nonnegative real numbers on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

Is it possible to have a Schur decomposition of a matrix $A=URU^H$ so that the upper triangular matrix $R$ only has real non-negative numbers on the diagonal?

I realize the diagonal of $R$ is typically made up of the eigenvalues of $A$ which are not necessarily positive or real, but since $U$ isn't completely unique maybe there's a way to set it up?

Not sure how to prove or disprove this.

Comment: The spectrum of a matrix is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A simple counterexample is any negative-definite matrix $A$. In this case, we have

$$
\sum_k r_{kk} = \mathrm{tr}(R) = \mathrm{tr}(RU^HU) = \mathrm{tr}(URU^H) = \mathrm{tr}(A) = \sum_k\lambda_k < 0
$$

where $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ which are negative by assumption and $r_{kk}$ are the diagonal elements of $R$.

---

The freedom in $U$ reflects the freedom in the choice of bases for the eigenspaces of $A$ and does not alter the fact that the diagonal of $R$ consists of the eigenvalues of $A$. See the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Proof) of Schur's decomposition.

---

It is possible to write $A=URV^H$ where $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $R$ is upper triangular (in fact, diagonal) with non-negative real numbers on diagonal. This is the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).